# When Echoing html in Php, output is displayed in the clear

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm having a problem where I am trying to echo an html page after a user submits a form. After the submit button is pressed the user is redirected the email.php page that contains the php code below. The echo however returns the html content in the clear and is not formatted correctly.

**Here is my PHP Code:**

```
<?php
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
//ini_set("display_errors", "On");`

//$json_data=$_GET['track'];
//______________________________________
//Establish Connection
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=xxxx;dbname=xxxx;charset=utf8', 'xxxx', 'xxxx')
    or die("cannot open database");
//$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
//$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$sql = "INSERT INTO xxxx (xxxx, xxxx, xxxx, xxxx) VALUES (:email, :firstname, :lastname, :year :month :day)";

$params = array(
    ':email' => $_POST['email'],
    ':firstname' => $_POST['firstname'],
    ':lastname' => $_POST['lastname'],
    ':day' => $_POST['day'],
    ':month' => $_POST['month'],
    ':year' => $_POST['year']
);
$points = $db->prepare($sql);

echo "<html>
<head>
<title>XXXX Confrimation</title>
</head>
<body style='background-color:#f3f3f3; margin:0;'>
<div style='background-color:#0a5a92; padding: 10px;color:#f3f3f3; margin:0px;'>
<h2>Thank You for Signing up!</h2>
</div>
<div style='padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;'>
<p> If you did not subscribe to XXXX, please email <a href='mailto:XXXX@XXXX.com'>XXXX@XXXX.com</a> to unsubcribe.</p>
<br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>"
;
```

**Here is the output:**

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css"></style>
</head>
<body>
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>XXXX Confirmation</title>
    </head>
    <body style='background-color:#f3f3f3; margin:0;'>
    <div style='background-color:#0a5a92; padding: 10px;color:#f3f3f3; margin:0px;'>
    <h2>Thank You for Signing up!</h2>
    </div>
    <div style='padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;'>
    <p> If you did not subscribe to XXXX, please email <a href='mailto:XXXX@XXXX.com'>XXXX@XXXX.com</a> to unsubcribe.</p>
    <br/>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not the best with php and I am running on very limited knowledge. I am also running my site using wordpress. If you have any idea why this is happening please let me know. I have been searching through forums for over a week now and have had no luck in finding a solution.

------**EDIT**-------

I realized that I made a mistake in the headers of my php code that declared the content as a json file. Because this was a mistake of mine that has nothing to do with the question above I am going to delete this question. Thank you for posting your answers because without them I would not have seen this stupid mistake.

---------**EDIT**----------
Correction: I am going to up-vote those who have helped me instead, just incase someone else has an issue similar to this. I do not currently have the reputation to up-vote but I will as soon as I do. Thank you again.

Comment: What do you mean by "in the clear"? Normally that means "without encryption", but that doesn't make sense in this context. Is it showing the source code in the browser instead of rendering the page?

Comment: Do not forget to sort out the typo's in this if it's a production site.

Comment: It looks like you're including the PHP file from somewhere else. Are you showing the full code here? Are you using some framework? WordPress?

Comment: I am not familiar with wordpress, but it seems that the html is loaded inside an container inside the main page. It's my guess.

Comment: Also your PDO prepared statement never gets executed.

Comment: Does the html form you're using has a target set? I think @Cheluis is right. It's returning the page in some container.

Comment: **Quentin** Sorry I am trying to convey that the html code is being displayed with tags when rendered.

Comment: **h00ligan** I am using wordpress and I am pointing to the php file from a form on a wordpress page I created.

**Mouser** I saw the typos, thanks for pointing them out. My PDO statement seems to be executing fine though. All data is entered into the database correctly. The html form's target is the php file that contains the code above. 

**Cheluis** Do you have a suggestion as to what should be done if it is loaded under a container?

Comment: @AllenButler I didn't mean the action attribute, but a target attribute. Normally a form loads a new page in your case the php file. However if a target is set (to an iframe for example) your page is rendered into that iframe.

Comment: How's the output rendered when you just open the php file via the address bar of your browser?

Comment: @Mouser Oh I see what you mean. I don't have a target set so the php file is loaded under the same tab. I am not trying to have the confirmation appear in an iframe

Comment: @Mouser The output is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I made a mistake in the headers of my php code that declared the content as a json file. Because this was a mistake of mine that has nothing to do with the question I am going to accept this post as the answer and up-vote those who have helped me. Thank you for posting your answers because without them I would not have seen this stupid mistake.

Comment: Yes I thought of this after I posted. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you echo your content into a site which already has the basic `HTML` frame (open `html` tag etc.). If you look at your output, you can see that there are 2 `html`, 2 `body` and 2 `head` tags, which can only appear **once** per site. I guess your script echoes your script output into the `<pre>` tag.

Try this echo and see if it leads to your desired output:

```
echo "
<body style='background-color:#f3f3f3; margin:0;'>
<div style='background-color:#0a5a92; padding: 10px;color:#f3f3f3; margin:0px;'>
<h2>Thank You for Signing up!</h2>
</div>
<div style='padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;'>
<p> If you did not subscribe to XXXX, please email <a href='mailto:XXXX@XXXX.com'>XXXX@XXXX.com</a> to unsubcribe.</p>
<br/>
</div>";
```

Comment: I tried this and had no luck. The output is still rendered in a <pre> ".." </pre> pair

Answer (score 0):

You already have a db connection open in wordpress by default. Use below as a example....handle the submit on the same page and redirect to another page pulling the information again (this will be important if they press the refresh button) So instead of the pdo function you can use:

```
if($_POST):

    global $wpdb;
    $data[]=$_POST['value'];
    $wpdb->insert( 'wp_custom', $data);

    if($wpdb->insert_id):
       $url= get_site_url().'/rest of the url'.'id='.$wpdb->insert_id;
       wp_redirect($url);
       exit();
    endif; 
endif;

get_header(); // will apply html and title tags.....check your theme for the the correct div / section to start html code with.
?>
<form action="" ></form>
```

redirected page:

```
if($_GET['id']):
   $info = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->custom WHERE id = $_GET['id']");
endif;

?>
<section class=""></section>
```

Also you need to look at security - look up santize_text_field() 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: ps just to clarify - html / title tags are added by the header in wordpress. You should not enter them again.

Comment: Can I still use my array variables through this method? I like the idea of parameterizing my statement.

Comment: yes but now they will be contained in the $info object so fetch like  `$info->columnname`  or do you mean the $_POST values for submission? just keep adding to $data e.g `$data[]= $_POST['value2']`